# Setting up custom locale ID Angular (currently ^5.2.0) applications

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular5, angular-i18n

I am trying to use locale ID "no-no" while serving building my app as following:

```
ng serve --aot --locale no-no
```

But it reports error as following:

```
Unable to load the locale data file "@angular/common/locales/no-no", please check that "no-no" is a valid locale id.
```

I explored about it and came to know about some breaking changes in Angular:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20340

After this I tried to setup custom locale as directed [here](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)
in **app.module.ts**

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeNB from '@angular/common/locales/nb';
registerLocaleData(localeNB, 'no-no');
```

Still facing the same problem!!
Please let me know if there is any way to setup any custom locale ID.

Comment: I have reported one issue in Angular CLI project:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9772
Propsoed a fix as well:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/9791

Comment: My fix  has been accepted in CLI and will be available in next version of Angular CLI.